# Can we show algebraically that this is true?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

This problem is part of a larger proof I've been working on. Long story short, I'm trying to prove a particular explicit formula for the recursive function

$$
t(p, 0) = 0 \\
t(p, k+1) = \left\lfloor \dfrac{t(p, k)}{3} \right\rfloor + p
$$

where $p=2n+1, n \in \mathbb{N}$. The inductive step of proving my particular explicit formula includes the following question:

Can we show algebraically that

$$ \left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{3} \left\lfloor \dfrac{2n-1}{2(3^{k-1})} + \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor \ \ = \ \ (-1) \left\lfloor \dfrac{2n-1}{2(3^k)} + \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$$

is true for all $k,n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ ? I used Python to test it and it seems to be true, at least for all $k≤1000, \ n≤1000$. Can anyone prove this rigorously? I tried using induction on $k$ but was not successful. I did not try induction on $n$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See the method(s) used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489162/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Claim.** Let $m,n$ be integers with $n>0$ and $x$ a real number. Then
> $$\Bigl\lfloor \frac{-\lfloor x \rfloor+m}{n} \Bigr\rfloor = -\Bigl\lfloor \frac{x-m+n-1}{n} \Bigr\rfloor.$$

**Proof.**
We have
\begin{align}
\Bigl\lfloor \frac{-\lfloor x \rfloor+m}{n} \Bigr\rfloor 
&=\Bigl\lceil \frac{-\lfloor x \rfloor+m-n+1}{n} \Bigr\rceil\tag{1}\\
&=-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor-m+n-1}{n} \Bigr\rfloor\tag{2}\\
&=-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\lfloor x-m+n-1 \rfloor}{n} \Bigr\rfloor\tag{3}\\
&=-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{ x-m+n-1 }{n} \Bigr\rfloor\tag{4}
\end{align}
where we used well-known identities:

1. $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right \rfloor = \left \lceil \frac{n-m+1}{m} \right \rceil$
2. $\lfloor -x \rfloor=-\lceil x \rceil$ (see [Proving that the $\lfloor-x\rfloor= -\lceil x\rceil$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163742))
3. $\lfloor x+m \rfloor=\lfloor x \rfloor +m$ (see [Find the value of $\lfloor x+y \rfloor$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348644))
4. $\lfloor \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{n} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor$ (see [How to prove or disprove $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}, \forall n\in\Bbb{N},n\gt 0\implies \lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\rfloor$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733848))

$\square$

Set $m=1,n=3,x=\dfrac{2n-1}{2(3^{k-1})} + \dfrac{1}{2}$ to get your result.

**Note.** Adding the ceiling version of the claim as an exercise and to make search engines happy (same $m,n,x$ restrictions):
$$
\Bigl\lceil \frac{-\lceil x \rceil+m}{n} \Bigr\rceil = -\Bigl\lceil \frac{x-m-n+1}{n} \Bigr\rceil.
$$

Comment: Wow, very elegant solution. Thank you. Would this still work if n was negative?

Comment: @SNN For negative $n$ it wouldn't work, for example try $x=m=0$ and $n=-1$ and you will get $0=-2$. The 1. and 4. equalities in the proof both require denominator to be positive. (Though this $n$ is different from $n$ in your statement, which holds for any integers $k,n$)

Comment: @SNN Above is essentially the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489162/242) (and likely many other prior answers).

Answer (score 2):

Let $q = \dfrac{2n-1}{2\cdot 3^k}$, and so $\dfrac{2n-1}{2\cdot 3^{k-1}} = 3q$. Both $q$ and $3q$ are is always positive and never an integer for $k,n = 1,2,3, \ldots$.

Converting the RHS into an inequality,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\left(q+\dfrac12\right) -1 <& \left\lfloor q+\dfrac12\right\rfloor &\le q+\dfrac12\\
-q+\dfrac12 >& -\left\lfloor q+\dfrac12\right\rfloor &\ge -q-\dfrac12 
\end{array}$$

There is exactly one integer in this range.

From the LHS, consider the content inside the outer $\lfloor \ \rfloor$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac13 - \frac13\left\lfloor 3q+\frac12\right\rfloor
&= -\frac13\left\lfloor-1+3q+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&= -\frac13\left\lfloor3q-\frac12\right\rfloor
\end{align*}\\
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left(3q-\dfrac12\right)-1<& \left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor &\le 3q-\dfrac12\\
-q+\dfrac12>& -\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor &\ge -q+\dfrac16\\
\end{array}$$

The middle $-\frac13\left\lfloor3q-\frac12\right\rfloor$ is a third of an integer. That means its floor satisfy a tighter inequality:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\left(-\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor\right) -\dfrac23 \le& \left\lfloor-\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor\right\rfloor &\le -\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor\\
\left(-q+\dfrac16\right) -\dfrac23 \le& \left\lfloor-\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor\right\rfloor &< -q+\dfrac12\\
-q -\dfrac12 \le& \left\lfloor-\dfrac13\left\lfloor3q-\dfrac12\right\rfloor\right\rfloor &< -q+\dfrac12\\
\end{array}$$

There is also exactly one integer in this range, and this matches the range of the RHS. So

$$LHS = \left\lfloor\frac13 - \frac13\left\lfloor \dfrac{2n-1}{2\cdot 3^{k-1}}+\frac12\right\rfloor\right\rfloor = -\left\lfloor \dfrac{2n-1}{2\cdot 3^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor = RHS.$$

Comment: This is a very interesting and clever solution. However, I'm inclined to accept @Sil's answer because it proves my equality directly by algebraic steps, and it's shorter. Still, your answer has taught me a new way to prove equalities with floor and ceiling functions (i.e. squeezing expressions inside a range of size 1). Thank you.